# Is it sometimes necessary to use multiple javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to web development and don't fully understand the role a js framework plays in an app. I've started with jQuery, but people have said I should try prototype.js or node.js for my project, which is a multiplayer strategy game.

Is it important to select a framework early on, and making sure it does everything you need so you don't have to use multiple frameworks?

Comment: These are different things, you can use most of them together as well. Node = server-side javascript, jQuery = divine witchery in form of JS library which does everything you could ever dream of.

Comment: Prototype.js is a bad idea (IMO) and would conflict with jQuery. node.js, on the other hand, is server-side and is completely unrelated and yes, you can use it. It would probably be well-suited to this situation, because it lets you interact with sockets rather easily.

Comment: @minitech. when you say `prototype` an `jQuery` conflicts do you mean the `$` symbol? because that's really not a "conflict".

Comment: Nodejs.org websockets.io and Please... jQuery is a js tool.. you wouldnt use a language tool without a understanding of the language.

Comment: @gdoron: It's partially the name, yes, but the real conflict is just using them both; I've been the unfortunate maintainer of one such project, and it's a nightmare.

Comment: @minitech. I would love to read an example. (except of the `$` var) thanks!

Comment: @gdoron: Read an example of... what? A bad mish-mash of plugins using both libraries? Here ya go: http://www.islandsportsnews.net/ And that's just different plugins with different libraries. One plugin with both would probably have made me quit the job on sight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm new to web development and don't fully understand the role a js
>   framework plays in an app

**You are new but you are lucky!**

Few years ago developers had really hard time working around cross browser issues in terms of CSS (still bit of it there), event handling, animations, DOM manipulation. You had to write differnet code for each browser quite often.

The JavaScript libraries came to life and solved the problem of developers, they do all the magic behind the scenes and you write the same code (almost always) to work in each browser. In other words, JavaScript libraries take it on their own to solve cross-browser issues by providing you with consistent set of functions to use for any browser.

Generally, JavaScript libraries take care of these or provide these options:

- Cross-browser issues handling
- Animation
- Custom dialogs and widgets
- Ability to write lesser code
- Specific selector engine
- Creation/Modification of DOM
- Event Handling
- Utility Functions
- AJAX

> I've started with jQuery, but people have said I should try
>   prototype.js or node.js for my project, which is a multiplayer
>   strategy game.

Essentially they do the same thing (mentioned above), it is up to you to decide which one you would go for. I like jQuery personally since it is easy to start with and has CSS-Like selector mechanism.

Node.JS is completely different beast, unlike jQuery or Prototype which base on client-side JavaScript, node.js is server-side JavaScript.

> Is it important to select a framework early on, and making sure it
>   does everything you need so you don't have to use multiple frameworks?

It isn't important unless you need it eg depending on your needs. Though I would personally suggest you to *learn the JavaScript itself first* so that when you come to a JavaScript library later, you should be able to make most of it.

Answer (score 4):

The role of a javascript framework is very simple: to give you a set of higher level functionality so that you can build your application without having to recode things which have been done before and to provide a structure for development.  You could think of jQuery or prototype.js as sets of functions which other people have found often need to be written again and again so they have already done it for you.  Things like animating objects on the screen, or merging and rearranging elements in the DOM are common to many applications so these frameworks and many others try to simplify these common tasks.  The other nice thing is they have solved common problems for you in the *best possible way for each platform* so no matter what browser or phone, you get a similar experience -- this didn't used to be the case.

Node.js is something different.  It is a server side language (of course the language is javascript) but it takes the role of php or perl or python or ruby (or your favorite server side lang) in that it actually runs code to talk to databases and fetch pages on the server while the others run code on the users' machines in browsers normally.

I would recommend just choosing one framework and learning it well (my personal vote is jQuery because of the wide developer base, [nice plugins](http://jqueryui.com/demos/), the good [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), and the understandability of code) but since each of these is just normal javascript under the hood, anything you can't do in one you can bridge with normal javascript. Practically you can do anything in any of them, just some tasks will be simpler in one framework than another.  When working with several, while they may not actively conflict it will be a development nightmare.

For your particular application you will need both a front end an backend to make it work.  If the app you are trying to build is a website then by all means go with one of these javascript frameworks but if you are talking about a mobile app on android or iphone you don't event need these.

Comment: +1 Well said. And to the OP, yes, you should choose just one JS framework. I recommend jQuery.

Comment: OP You should not just choose one - though jQuery can offer a lot of the functionallity you will ever require - you can mix and match the frameworks to your needs

Comment: While you can -- I would argue that you should not.  You will have to remember not only how to use each one, but when you come back to your code months later which parts are in which framework and which can 'work together' easily since they are in the same framework. Also if you have many developers (or even just more than one) you really want to stick to one so they can work together easily.

Comment: "You could think of jQuery or prototype.js as sets of functions which other people have found often need to be written again and again" I've been coding in Java and Actionscript so this makes a lot of sense. Well put indeed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just extending what has been put in comments and clarifying what these 'frameworks' are:

You can use as many frameworks as you like and they should (if they have been written well) not conflict with each other. There may be issues with some libraries as they assign to special characters such as $ and as there are a limited amount of special chars not already used in javascript this is almost inevitable BUT usually the more mature frameworks have identified this and have written work arounds i.e. jQuery.noConflict which basically reassigns whatever was using $ before.

As for each framework there are loads and each has it's own particular niche/API suited to a particular programming need such as:

Sizzle (used in jquery) - Excellent selector syntax for maniuplating DOM

jQuery - excellent plugin architecture, mature API which does a hell of a lot of the common programming requirements out there, excellent UI components when combined with jQuery UI

Handlebars.js - template based dom manipulation + some other nice MVVM (?)

Sproutcore.js, node.js... etc etc - have a read up on each and see what they say the framework is aimed at.

You can mix them together - you may find the occasional conflict which you should report to the authors but don't feel confined to one framework.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to be bewildered by the range of available frameworks - these days it can seem like a new one enters the zeitgeist every month.

The key is to use the ones that work for you, and, crucially, to understand that not all frameworks and libraries do the same thing.

jQuery, for example, is centered around DOM manipulation and AJAX. Yes it has more facets, but these are its selling points. Compare that with, say, Underscore.js, which is all about enriching the data-level API to be more akin to something like, say, PHP. JavaScript, after all, has a traditionally limiting API compared to such languages (though it's getting richer all the time with successive ECMA releases and vendor-specific APIs).

Node.js, as hackartist mentioned in his answer, is totally unrelated to both of the above in that it is server-side, not client.

I would avoid, particularly at your early stage, using multiple libraries that are similar in focus. You come across projects that load in both jQuery UI and, say, extJS. Yes this gives you more to play with but, given the overlap, the benefit is outweighed by the negative impact on your page's load weight. Go with the one that you like the look of and, crucially, whose docs and community you feel comfortable with.

Finally, bear in mind libraries and frameworks are not really the same thing, though the terms of often used somewhat inadvisably interchangeably. They are both JS under the hood; a library is geared towards the provision of functions and patterns that, at least usually, mean writing less code than you would if you did it all in native, or 'vanilla', JavaScript, while a framework is concerned with the over-arching structure of your code and how the various parts relate or interoperate.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers everyone. These explanations are excelent an well detailed. I have a good feel for the way it works now.